# Set focus to textinput after transition ended

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

Is there a way to set the focus - so that typing automatically goes into the text input field - after a transition ended? I want then the user types the keyboard inputto go automatically go into the textinput field. If possible, can one do it with `CSS` only? Or is `JavaScript` (no jQuery!) needed?
Something like

```
document.getElementByClassName('text-input').focus();
```

doesn't do it.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="element"></div>
  <input class="text-input" type="text" name="search" />
</div>


.wrapper {
  height: 40px;
  width: 75px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  border-color: red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-left:30px;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.element {
  background-color: hotpink;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}

.wrapper:hover {
  width: 100%;
}

.text-input {
  max-width: 0;
  float: left;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px transparent;
  -webkit-transition:max-width 0.6s ease-in-out;
  transition:max-width 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.wrapper:hover .text-input {
  max-width: 50%;
  padding: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
}
```

**Here is a codepen**

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MqjmQz

Comment: I don't think it is possible to focus on an element using pure CSS. Are you unable to use the HTML DOM focus() method?

Comment: @Lesleyvdp that doesnt work. The Focus gets not set. I assume its because of the transition?

Comment: Just so you know for future reference, you don't have to worry about the transition at all.  It works if you set focus after the input... https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zJKzKr

Comment: @Stophface Check my edited answer as well. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go. Pure JS Solution

```js
document.getElementById("wrapper").onmouseover = function()
{
setTimeout(function(){mouseOver()},600)
};


function mouseOver(){
document.getElementById('inputField').focus();
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 40px;
  width: 75px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  border-color: red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-left:30px;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.element {
  background-color: hotpink;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}

.wrapper:hover {
  width: 100%;
}

.text-input {
  max-width: 0;
  float: left;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px transparent;
  -webkit-transition:max-width 0.6s ease-in-out;
  transition:max-width 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.wrapper:hover .text-input {
  max-width: 50%;
  padding: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper" id="wrapper">
  <div class="element"></div>
  <input class="text-input" id="inputField" type="text" name="search" />
</div>
```

**Edit**
You can also call a mouseout function so that whenever the cursor goes out, the field get blur.

```js
document.getElementById("wrapper").onmouseover = function()
{
setTimeout(function(){mouseOver()},600)
};
document.getElementById("wrapper").onmouseleave = function()
{
mouseOut()
};


function mouseOver(){
document.getElementById('inputField').focus();
}
function mouseOut(){
document.getElementById('inputField').blur();
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 40px;
  width: 75px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  border-color: red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-left:30px;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.element {
  background-color: hotpink;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}

.wrapper:hover {
  width: 100%;
}

.text-input {
  max-width: 0;
  float: left;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px transparent;
  -webkit-transition:max-width 0.6s ease-in-out;
  transition:max-width 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.wrapper:hover .text-input {
  max-width: 50%;
  padding: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper" id="wrapper">
  <div class="element"></div>
  <input class="text-input" id="inputField" type="text" name="search" />
</div>
```

Comment: This does work but I can't +1 it, because it's misleading.  The only problem was that focus wasn't being set.  It has nothing to do with the transition, so all the code related to that is overkill and will just lead to unnecessary bloated code.

Comment: Read the title :) it says : 'Set focus to textinput after transition ended' . The "after transition ended" part can't be done without this

Comment: Yes it can - there are transition end events.  But aside from that, it's clear that the OP only *thinks* they need to set focus after the transition.  They just want the input to have focus.  This answer is vastly misleading as the OP now believes that to be the case and will go forward thinking that and bloat every single project they work on, until someone corrects them.

Comment: But if you go for webkitTransitionEnd or transitionend, it will end up creating browser compatibility issues. While the onmouseover and onmouseleave is widely supported I believe

Comment: Between these -> `transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd` everything is covered for all up-to-date platforms.  If the platform is not up-to-date then a simple `element.focus()` is the *only* foolproof answer.  Using a `setTimeout()` is a hack, and doesn't take into account the fact that the transition time can change.  But, it will still work because the `setTimeout()` is simply unnecessary.  Just want to make sure you understand this, as I've already exampled this to the OP.

Answer (score 3):

I see other solutions, it's better to use `transitionend` event listener. Just adding one more way to do so. Please have a look.

**JS:**

```
var txtInput = document.querySelector('.text-input');

txtInput.addEventListener("transitionend", function(e){
  document.getElementById('inputField').focus();
}, false)
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MqjmQz

Comment: Great! I was not aware about `transitioned` event

Answer (score -3):

There's no such feature I fear, but as you know how long the transition take (0.6s) you can use a `setTimeout`.

```js
var wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper');
wrapper.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    wrapper.classList.add('focus');
    document.querySelector('.text-input').focus();
  }, 600)
});
```

Then you need some CSS changes to prevent shrink when mouse goes out.

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 40px;
  width: 75px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  border-color: red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-left:30px;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.element {
  background-color: hotpink;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}

.wrapper:hover,
.wrapper.focus {
  width: 100%;
}

.text-input {
  max-width: 0;
  float: left;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px transparent;
  -webkit-transition:max-width 0.6s ease-in-out;
  transition:max-width 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.wrapper:hover .text-input,
.wrapper.focus .text-input{
  max-width: 50%;
  padding: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
}
```

https://codepen.io/lucafbb/pen/Eegmrx?editors=1111

Comment: That doesn't work. When I start typing the page reloads and the typed stuff appears over the bordered div.

Comment: You should post code *in the answer*.  Include a demo link if required, but an answer with just a link is not an answer at all.